# Centroid of connected 3D shapes

Tags: centroid

This might be a dumb question, but I tried to search for answers online and couldn't find any. I couldn't find too much information about centre of mass of irregular 3D objects in general. So, I have three 3D shapes which are connected to each other, a cylinder, and two cones. The cones are not isosceles and are connected to the cylinder at an angle. The first cone forms with the cylinder an angle of 190 degrees, and the other 200. There should be a picture of the system with my post [Connected 3D objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxhvE.png).

Assuming that I can find the centre of mass of each object by itself, my question is: How can I now find the centre of mass of the entire system?

Note: No mathematical calculations are required in any answer to this question. I would just greatly appreciate an explanation to how one might find the centre of mass of a system of connected 3D objects, knowing the centre of mass of each object individually and the weights.

Comment: Here is your answer with another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653903/center-of-mass-multivariable-calculus/653946). You just need to figure out the equation and limits of the shape.

Comment: Take the centroid of the centroids.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the mass and the center of mass of each object then the center of mass of the union (as long as they are disjoint - they don't need to be connected) is simply the center of mass of three point masses: the vector sum of the three centers of mass weighted by the masses scaled to sum to $1$.